# Should established questions be closed due to newer close reasons?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I came across a question on SO that's about six years old with over 460 upvotes which asks for opinions, recommendations, and best practices (part of the question has the text, "My question is: what is the current commonly accepted best practice way to organize your actual code? ").

I'm pretty sure that when it was originally asked, that the:

> Primarily opinion-based -  Many good questions generate some degree
>   of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question
>   will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts,
>   references, or specific expertise.

close reason didn't exist yet. The question has over a dozen answers and was protected back in 2011. The question itself is well-written and clear, however there's no actual code involved, and the entire point of it appears to be to solicit opinions on "best practices".

Let me be clear in saying that  I'm not campaigning that the question be closed. My goal here is to find out how close reasons should be applied, since they do change from time to time. I am asking if now, since it appears to fit the above close reason which may not have existed when it was written, should the question be closed regardless of the length of time it's been around and the number of answers and votes that it received?

Again I don't believe the age of the question is a reason to close it. But should what appears to be a popular question be closed now, since the close reasons have changed from when it was first written, or does it receive a pardon?

For those interested, this is the question in question: [Commonly accepted best practices around code organization in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247209/current-commonly-accepted-best-practices-around-code-organization-in-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: FWIW, the policies actually haven't changed *that much* over the years - we've just better refined the close reasons to more accurately depict what is and is not on-topic for our site.

Comment: I believe that there are some questions that the mods have decided to keep around "for historical reasons" even though the current rules would have had them closed. (Kind of like how "heritage" buildings are protected from the wrecking ball.) Usually, you can tell which questions those are, because the mods will have attached some kind of notice to that effect to them.

Comment: @cybermonkey - You downvote on meta to disagree. If you feel that this is a dupe, vote to close it instead.

Comment: @j08691 **One** of the reasons is to disagree, others include bad questions and duplicates.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, questions that are *now* off-topic should be closed.

We like to keep the site clean, and when we learn that certain question types don't work for us then that means pre-existing questions of that type need to be closed too, however long it takes to find them later.

Also, closing older posts prevents people from pointing to those posts as arguments to keep their new posts open, so closing older posts that are now off-topic is a form of [fixing broken windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).

Comment: Isn't one of the motivators of this is that people whose new questions get closed point to these older questions as examples of why their question should remain open?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: yes, the broken windows principle; if you want to stop vandalism, fix your broken windows so's not to give the impression that breaking windows is an okay thing to do.

Comment: Surprisingly, there are still [a few dozen recommendation questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&newwindow=1&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+-site%3Arads.stackoverflow.com+recommend+best+book+-%22closed+as%22+-%22locked+by%22+-%22put+on+hold+as%22+-%22marked+as+duplicate%22&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+-site%3Arads.stackoverflow.com+recommend+best+book+-%22closed+as%22+-%22locked+by%22+-%22put+on+hold+as%22+-%22marked+as+duplicate%22&gs_l=serp.3...3805.12507.0.12764.39.23.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..39.0.0.Mhw0pefMMq8) that haven't been closed yet.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: moderators keep finding them all the time (usually when someone flagged a spam or link-only answer on one of them). That's not unexpected.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I closed the first 50 or so of them. They were all older and had a low view count (so few people ever looked at them recently). Community moderation can't ever be perfect, but it works better than other systems so far!