# Is it valid to dup-close an old question against a newer one?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413118/adding-numbers-in-java): a super-basic thing, which should (and could!) have been closed as DUP the day it was asked 6 years ago.

So I picked a good DUP (written **before** that question); and closed it.

Would it have been "valid" to point to a *newer* duplicate also?

( I am asking specifically about "future duplicates" ; as questions like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280957/should-established-questions-be-closed-due-to-newer-close-reasons) seem to focus on "off topic" in general )

Bonus question: should that old question be downvoted and deleted; as it really seemed to work as BS-magnet?

Comment: Not in this case, it won't be (as this question is a multi-ulti-dupe but should be closed as a dupe of the canonical, whichever that may be).