# Why is my question rejected as 'opinion based', when other opinion based questions are not?

Tags: discussion

I've recently had a question on SO deleted because it was deemed opinion based: [What is a better technique than this to control Flutter animation speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485183/what-is-a-better-technique-than-this-to-control-flutter-animation-speed)

I can't understand why my best practice question got rejected pro forma, while others that follow the same pattern like [What is your opinion of the Telerik Extensions for MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864804/what-is-your-opinion-of-the-telerik-extensions-for-mvc) remain. Is it just because the question I referenced is so old?

Is there a different Stack Exchange site to which best practice questions should be posted?

Comment: The other question is not on-topic either. It was flagged for closure a couple times in its history but probably aged out of the close queue due to the sheer number of off-topic questions on SO. Your question could well be on-topic on [Code Review](codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Never, ever compare your questions with old questions. Lots of old questions have snuck past moderation systems, and are handled appropriately when they come to light. With 20+ million questions, it's not easy to monitor every single question on the site. The question you linked is already on its way to being closed

Comment: I'm curious, anyone know what [this means?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8853077) `Community♦ reviewed this Jul 22 '15 at 5:58: Close` But the question was never closed - and even then, I thought Community only closed when OP agreed with a duplicate suggestion, and this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: see also: [Should established questions be closed due to newer close reasons?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280957/839601)

Comment: @CertainPerformance that’s a review by a now-deleted user, they had picked ‘Close’.

Comment: @CurtEckhart Welcome to Meta SO! Please see [gorilla vs shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/).

Comment: Thanks for comments everyone, but most of you have misinterpreted my question here too. I have never been challenging the status quo, just looking for a forum where my original question can be posed and receive a constructive answer.


I didn't come here to battle anyone. SO is great and I have no bone to pick there. I'm only searching for a better answer to my original question, and it is by it's nature an invitation for opinion. Expert opinion. Seeking advice from those who are more proficient at Flutter animation.


Does such a forum exist in the SO universe?

Comment: @ggorlen - Pretty funny story, but I wasn't asking if Superman can beat Batman in a fight. I was asking originally for advice on a better technique of controlling flutter animations than the one I implemented. I know that could go horribly wrong, but it also could have resulted in a Flutter expert pointing me to features in the framework that I didn't know about. That was my hope. I think the designation of 'opinion based' was because I asked for "opinions" in my original question and I got keyword flagged.

Comment: Also this discussion is gloriously so, so meta. Its entertainment value is priceless, and I mean that in the most good natured way. Seems like SO-meta is serving its function.

Comment: tbh, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/293910) is the most illuminating answer to my q I found. I love answers backed by data.

Comment: @CurtEckhart I think you're reading the link too literally. It's not a matter of _fights_. The point is that opinion-based questions ("which is better..." and variants) are off-topic on Stack Exchange as indicated by that canonical blog post by the founder of Stack Overflow along with the duplicate which answers your second question and [related answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252780/6243352) to the same effect.

Comment: @ggorlen - I appreciate your insights. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

Think of it this way: if you got a speeding ticket, would you complain to the judge about all of the other people that didn't get them? The fact that many speeders don't get caught is not proof that people who do get caught don't deserve tickets.

Stack Overflow gets a large number of questions per day, and there are a relatively small number of people moderating it, so many low-quality questions simply "slip through the cracks."

Note too that, now that you pointed this out, that question is also closed.

Comment: I was concerned that making reference to a similar issue would start the flames and it looks like I have my answer here. I didn't post to receive chastisement, just an answer to my original question (which still is unanswered in my world). Making reference to another issue only served to obfuscate my original question and I'm sorry for that. Circling back to my original objective, I only want to know if there is a forum where a questions seeking best practice advice that are of necessity 'an opinion' is appropriate. Can anyone name such a place?